# Object vs Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

While typing the value {2,4,45,50} on console displays 50, but assigning the  {2,4,45,50} to variable getting the error

```
    var a = {2,4,45,50}
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

What is the concept on this.

Comment: its `[]` for arrays, the console just treats your `{}` like a block and gives you the last value

Comment: @govinda Do you mean `var a = [2, 4, 45, 50]`?

Comment: in that case why are we getting the error on assign to variable , should set 50 to the variable as per my understanding

Comment: It is not a valid json object, you cannot just put numbers in a JSON

Comment: @Raptor no i will get the arguments as {2,4,45,50},  need this as array while trying that logic got this scenario

Comment: @Govindaraj if you need an array, make it an array instead of an (invalid) object.

Comment: @GertB.I agree in that case we should not get 50 also without variable , as per my understanding

Comment: @Govindaraj No, the object creation, as the error states, does not expect a number, but a string. It's an invalid json, so it throws an error. Outputting in the console is different.

Comment: @Govindaraj `{1, 2, 3}` does not make an array in JS, nor is it a valid expression, so of course assigning it to a variable will throw -- the `{}` creates a block, or a set of statements, and the console typically gives you the last value when given a set of expressions -- even typing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` into the console yields `5`

Comment: Not sure what you are confused about, all you need to do is either replace the `{}` with `[]` --- or you can use `Array(2,4,45,50)`

Answer (score 3):

> its [] for arrays, the console just treats your {} like a block and gives you the last value –
> skara9

As Skara mentioned, `[]` is for arrays. `{}` is for tables, so when you assign it to a variable since it's a table it's expecting a key and value, for example: `{a: 1, b:2, 3:4}`. If you want an array then change `{}` to `[]`, otherwise, you should assign a key and value for the table.

If you would like to log a specific value of an array you can do so using an index, index starts from 0 to the number of values. For example:

```js
 var a = [2,4,45,50]
 console.log(a[0])
 //Expected output is 2
```

If you wanted to use a table and log the value of the first key, which in this case would be `a`, then you would do:

```js
 var test = {a:2, b:4, c:45, d:50}
 console.log(test.a)
 //Expected output is 2 because 2 is assigned to a
```

You could also just log the whole array and/or table.